# Consequence of random walk with positive speed on a graph

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, random-walk

Consider a random walk $X(n)$ on a vertex-transitive graph where the random walk has positive speed,
i.e., $$ \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{d(X(n), X(0))}{n}= \alpha>0$$ almost surely. Let $A_n$ be the set of vertices having a graph distance $n$ from $X(0)$. Let $T_n$ be the difference between the first time the random walk hits $A_n$ and the last time the random walk hits $A_n$.

I need to prove that all the $T_n$ are stochastically smaller than a variable $T$, which is almost surely finite.

Is this condition true for any vertex-transitive graph, or are additional conditions necessary in order it to hold? For example, if the graph is a regular tree, this is easy to prove, as such a problem is equivalent to the same problem for biased random walk on $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: This cannot be true in full generality hence, if true, it must rely on some specific features of the model.

Comment: Why cannot be true in full generality?

Comment: Because the first and last hitting times of $n$ could be $n/\alpha\pm\sqrt{n}U_n$ where $(U_n)$ is oscillating, say, between $0$ and $+1$.

Comment: Perhaps vertex transitivity prevents this to happen, as from the point of view of the site everything should look similar. However, I edited the question.